# Change div position after refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 div like this code :-

```
<div class="row" id="wrapper">
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

and when click refresh button

```
<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
```

We change my div, But i need when refresh my page, Change my div.

So, I don't need to click on refresh, I need when open page change the position of div every time

My Javascript code is :-

```
        var chain = [
            document.getElementById("div1"),
            document.getElementById("div2"),
            document.getElementById("div3")
        ],
        wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
        refresh = document.getElementById("refresh");

        refresh.onclick = function() {
            chain.push( chain.shift() );
            for ( var i=0, len = chain.length; i < len; i++ ) {
                var el = chain[i];
                wrapper.removeChild(el);
                wrapper.appendChild(el);
            };
            console.log(chain);
        };
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vo85f65o/1/ - sorry.. what do you want to do

Comment: can you  be more specific

Comment: I think you need this action on page refresh not on refresh button click right? as i know for that you need server side code.

Comment: If you want to refresh the page, you can set a cookie and, at page refresh, check if the cookie exists and call your reorder function. Then remove the cookie.

Comment: you'll need to set some flag in persistence such as sessionStorage. the web is stateless

Comment: I dont need to click on refresh, I need when open page change the position of div

Comment: @ZamalekMan So you should try the cookie method that I commented above

Answer (score 0):

If you want that you will have to use cookies! mmm...
anyway about cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Code:

```
document.cookie="height: 99px";
```

Now you can

```
document.getElementById("div1").height(document.cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you can use a cookie to control if the page was refreshed.
You can control when the user unload the page, so, it would be something like:

```
var chain = [
    document.getElementById("div1"),
    document.getElementById("div2"),
    document.getElementById("div3")
],
    wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
    refresh = document.getElementById("refresh");

refresh.onclick = function() {
    chain.push( chain.shift() );
    for ( var i=0, len = chain.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var el = chain[i];
        wrapper.removeChild(el);
        wrapper.appendChild(el);
    };
    console.log(chain);
};  

/////////////////////

if( !!getCookie('refresh') == location.pathname ){
    setCookie('refresh', '', -1);
    refresh.click();
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    setCookie('refresh', location.pathname, 1);
};

/////////////////////

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can [check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/be0x2777/). Remember that jsFiddle changes the path (it adds "/show/") so you have to try it in your environment, the jsfiddle is valid to see how the cookie is stored and the code works.

**edit**:
To try it in the fiddle, change the cookie value to some string (replace `location.pathname` by `"yes"`), so it should work as expected.